# Metasyntax and tools for network communication "grammar"?

Tags: .net, parsing, network-programming

Is there some lex+yacc-like tool for implementing network communication "grammar"? I'm not sure "grammar" is the term used for this, but this is what I mean:

A conversation between a client and the server begins with

```
Client                              Server
       ---Client hello------------->
       <--Server hello--------------
```

Then, it continues with repetitions of either

```
Client                              Server
       ---Get number of Foo items-->
       <--Number of Foo items-------
```

or

```
Client                              Server
       ---Get list of Baz items---->
       <--List of Baz items---------
```

The grammar in question in an EBNF:ish metasyntax would be something like

```
<start> = <client hello> , <server hello> , { <client request> } ;
<client request> = <get number of Foo items> , <number of Foo items>
                 | <get list of Baz items> , <number of Baz items> ;
```

Is there anything like this for describing the client/server conversation and are there any tools (primarily for .NET) to aid the implementation of the conversation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could model each agent with a finite-state automaton, that showed how it reacted to messages.  (Two agents --> 2 FSAs, one for each).

The complete behavior of the system is then the crossproduct of the FSAs.  A tool may want to compute that, but people pretty much will rather see the individual FSAs.

A good generalization of FSAs are [Colored Petri Nets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coloured_Petri_net), which allows the agent to respond to the content of the messages as well as their existence, as well as handle various types of synchronization.  CPNs
exchange typed ("colored") values.

A key issue is the richness of the type system; I've never seen a CPN that could model parameterized types but I suspect that is just a matter of gluing the right type system to one, and then you can probably model "list of " as a color.

(If you use a CPN with only one kind of token that carries no value [traditionally colored "black"], and you don't use the CPN synchronization features, CPNs decay directly into FSAs.)

An apparantly very good toolset for managing and reasoning about CPNs can be found at: http://cpntools.org/   I have no specific experience with these tools, but have been following their development over the last 20 years with keen interest.

Each of these formalisms has limits.   For instance, you might want to model the fact that the number of messages exchanged between two agents is a Mersenne prime.  Neither FSAs nor standard CPNs can do this.  The problem is much like the issue "conventional BNF" being unable to model context-sensitive languages.

Usually you trade the ability to do arbitrary computations for convenience of expression and reasoning.   That is why FSAs are more popular than CPNs (where FSAs are usable), and CPNs more useful than pure process calculi.

Comment: I'll problably settle for the traditional FSAs, but CPNs were new to me and quite inspirational.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any tool that could directly help you but you can read about [Dataflows in TPL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603) (for queuing and communication) and [Irony Project](https://irony.codeplex.com) for grammar.

You can write a "grammar" in Irony, create a grammar tree and, using custom **stateful** tree visitor, evaluate it basing on a type of a message that you've received. Stateful tree visitor will hold information where you are at the tree.

This solution is highly theoretical but I may become a starting point.